# How to get a value from controller and use this in javascript using MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my project , I get the error and success notifications as TempData from controller and in view , if they're not null I show user a notification seperately. Ever since I start to use FilePond , my TempData values became invisible. Hence, I try to add if-else conditions to javascript so I can show the notifications again. But the problem is , I can't get the TempData value to use in javascript. I researched and tried all recommendations but it still returns null. Any Idea how can I fix this ? I'm so close to end this but the only problem is TempData now.

My Controller (I made it shorter but in debug , I can get the tempdata value so nothing is wrong in here)

```
[HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SaveCommand command)
        {
           TempData["error"] = _localizationService.GetLocalizedHtmlString("error");
           return View();
        }
```

View / Javascript Part (var test returns null)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           
            var myJsVariable = null;

            var test = @Json.Serialize(@TempData["error"]);
          
            
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                pond = FilePond.create(
                    document.querySelector('#ImageUrl'), {
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    instantUpload: false,
                    allowProcess: true
                });

                var frm = $('#form2');
                if (myJsVariable != null) {
                   
                frm.submit(function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var formdata = new FormData(this);
                    
                    pondFiles = pond.getFiles();

                    for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
                       
                        formdata.append('ImageUrl', pondFiles[i].file);
                    }
                    pond.removeFiles(pondFiles);
                   
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/test/create/",
                        data: formdata,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        method: "post"
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        
                    });

                        $("#modal3").modal('show');

                })
        }
        else if(myJsVariable ==null){
                    console.log("fail")
                    frm.submit(function (e) {

                        e.preventDefault();
                        var formdata = new FormData(this);
                     
                        pondFiles = pond.getFiles();

                        for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
                            
                            formdata.append('ImageUrl', pondFiles[i].file);
                        }
                        pond.removeFiles(pondFiles);
                      
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/test/create/",
                            data: formdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            method: "post"
                        }).done(function (response) {
                          
                        });

                        $("#modal2").modal('show');
                    })
        }
            });
        </script>
    }
```

ps : This was a problem for a while so I created a random myJsVariable to understand where the problem is. But instead of using this , I need to use my tempdata values. (I cant even show my tempdata values inside my modals.)

Comment: I have 2 questions. Have you tried to hard code the value for `TempData["error"]` and did it work? Did you surround the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` with `@section Scripts{}`?

Comment: I don't understand the first question but this is all I did. And for the second , yes it's surrounded with section @TinyWang

Comment: [TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#tempdata-providers) seems to had a limitation for data length, so I was just afraid if the value is too long.. So I just want to confirm about it. Per my test, in a controller, I set `TempData["error"] = "asdf"` and in cshtml file, I write `@section Scripts{<script>var a = @Json.Serialize(@TempData["error"]); $("#cont").html(a);</script>}` and it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry  but #Cont is a id of what ? Could you explain it to me and share this as a solution ? @TinyWang

Comment: I just write a `<div id="cont"></div>` in the view to display whether it worked or not... I can't explain your symptom.

Answer (score 0):

> This was a problem for a while so I created a random myJsVariable to
> understand where the problem is. But instead of using this , I need to
> use my tempdata values. (I cant even show my tempdata values inside my
> modals.)

Well, the way are you trying to `Retrieve value` from `temp data` is incorrect. Here `''` is very important. You could use below pattern to extract your `@TempData["error"]` then bind to `javascript` easily.

```
 var tempData = ('@TempData["error"]');
```

**Working Example For You:**

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult TempDataView()
        {
            TempData["error"] = "Temp Data From Controller";
            return View();
        }
```

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="formModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="formModal">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a onclick="BindTempDataToJavascript('@Url.Action("TempDataView","Todo",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','Bind Temp Data To Javascript')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> Bind Temp Data To Javascript</a>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    BindTempDataToJavascript = (url, title) => {
        //Retriving Temp Data and Binding to Javascript variable
        var tempData = ('@TempData["error"]');
        alert(tempData);
        console.log(tempData);
        $("#formModal").find(".modal-body").html(tempData);
        $("#formModal").find(".modal-title").html(tempData);
        $("#formModal").modal('show');
    };
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]